# Anfroid Studio 1.5.1 ошибка Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

При создании клона игры Flappy Bird -"ругается" на класс `ResourceLoader` введите сюда код,не может загрузить лого, выделяет строку инициал-и logo в методе `load()`. В чём может быть дело?
Вот код ошибок:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:112)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite.<init>(Sprite.java:83)
 at pavel.example.flygame.loader.ResourceLoader.load(***ResourceLoader.java:23***)
 at pavel.example.flygame.FlyGame.create(***FlyGame.java:12***)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Вот строки, на которые идёт ссылка:

```
public static void load(){
    atlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("texture/texture.pack"),true);
    logo = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("logo"));
.....
}
```

и

```
public void create() {
    ResourceLoader.load();
    setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
}
```